# How to include a new view controller to an existing navigation view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing a basic which has a story board like this:
[image]

When the UIButton is pressed the URL is loaded. If the URL request is succesfull then I have the "Success" view (on on the right) opened.

It all works fine but I can't seem to get the navigation controller to appear on the Success view.
Could someone help me?  Also, if the navigation can go on that view, how would I add a "back" button to take the user back to the main view?

Here is my code so far:

```
UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", status_code);
UIViewController *linkSuccess = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"linkSuccess"];
[self presentViewController:linkSuccess
                   animated:YES
                 completion:NULL];
```

Peter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Control drag from the my app controller (the little yellow icon on the lower left in your screenshot) to the Success view controller and it should bring up the box asking you what kind of segue.  Because this is a navigation controller you want a push segue.  Click on the new arrow going from the my app controller to the success controller in the storyboard that represents your new segue and in the properties inspector give it a name, perhaps something like showSuccess

Then in your URL request successful code use this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSuccess" sender:self];
```

Alternatively, if you want to instantiate it yourself (as you have in the code above) you need to add it to the navigation controller.  For example:

```
UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", status_code);
UIViewController *linkSuccess = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"linkSuccess"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:linkSuccess animated:YES];
```

Comment: I just discovered the segue class feature and thought it might be along those lines.  I will give it a go!

Comment: It worked, but when I click the back button it doesn't take me back. Instead I get a back screen, then another back button saying "My App"?

Comment: Are you doing both code snippets or just one?  The navigation controller keeps track of the apps on the stack and as you go back will walk through them.  So if it works, but does not go back that means that the navigation controller has added two views instead of one.  The back button title should be the title of the previous view controller too - that is a clue that you have too many added.

Comment: It is going to that view automatically as soon as I click, then reading my code and going to that view. So it is going to that view twice.  How do I prevent it from it's default action?

Comment: I'm saying either use the segue in the storyboard, OR call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:linkSuccess animated:YES];` but not both.  It sounds like you have done both which means the storyboard pushes a controller, and your My App controller pushes another copy which makes two.

Comment: Yes. So how do I stop the storyboard from pushing the controller? The reason why I want the My App to push the controller is because of the if conditions in the m file.

Comment: Did you create the segue between your controllers or from the button to the controller?  If it is going from the button to the success controller it will fire when the button is pushed.  If it is from one controller to the other then it will only fire when you call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSuccess" sender:self];`

Comment: I used the button.  My bad!  Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: PUSH is deprecated. Use 'SHOW' instead of 'PUSH'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extending success view controller from 'My App' controller. Click on 'My App'view controller header, hold ctrl + click on trackpad + move it to success view controller.

Should be work

Comment: I tried that.  I get three options: modal, push and custom.  None of the three work.  Peter